# Merge JSON array to a single string

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a field named `qn` of JSONB type of this form:

`[{id: 1, text: 'A'}, {id: 2, text: 'B'}]`

To get all the text, I can do:

`SELECT jsonb_array_elements(qn)->>'text' from templates where id=1`

My question is, how can I merge into a single string like this:

`A, B`

If the field is not JSONB, it can be done easily using:

`SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(select title from templates), ', ');`

How do you do it if the field is JSONB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply aggregate into a string:

```
SELECT string_agg(txt, ', ') AS all_text
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(qn)->>'text' AS txt
  FROM templates
  WHERE id = 1) sub;
```

Comment: Tks, it works on this form. I was actually trying to use it at `to_tsvector`.
`setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(array_to_string(array(jsonb_array_elements(new.questions)->>'text'), ', '), '')), 'D');`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment. Topic starter needed tsvector column. I had such structure for text column named `article` with json data and needed search text in the key `text`:

```
{"time": "some time_structure", "data": {"blocks": [{"data": {"text": "Some long, long text", "image": "image_url"}}, {"data": {"text": "another long text"}}]}}
```

I generated tsvector field such way:

```
setweight(to_tsvector('russian'::regconfig, jsonb_path_query_array(article::jsonb, '$.blocks[*].data.text')), 'C')
```